# How to write expression for inputting multiple values in Mapbox JS setFilter() for filtration?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I can successfully pass single value in my mapbox setFilter() by using expressions like these:

```
var business_domain_values = {0 : 'Corporate', 1 : 'Industrial',
                                  2 : 'Infrastructure', 3 : 'Institutional',
                                  4 : 'Commercial', 5 : 'Residential', 
                                  6 : 'Healthcare', 7 : 'Science & Technology', 
                                  8 : 'Financial Facilities'};

map.setFilter('AW', ['any', ['in', 'Corporate', ['get', 'Business_Unit']]]); 
                              OR
map.setFilter('Key Prospect', ['==', ['get', 'Business_Unit'], business_domain_values[0]]);
```

However, I want to pass multiple values like Commercial, Industrial etc. for filtering out. Trying hard to build expressions like

Approach #1.

```
 map.setFilter('AW', ['any', ['in', ['Corporate', 'Industrial'], ['get', 'Business_Unit']]]);
```

This resulted in

evented.js:145 Error: layers.AW.filter[1][1][0]: Unknown expression "Corporate". If you wanted a literal array, use ["literal", [...]].

Approach #2.

```
map.setFilter('AW', ['any', ['in', ['literal', ['Corporate', 'Industrial']], ['get', 'Business_Unit']]]);
```

This resulted in

evented.js:145 Error: layers.AW.filter[1]: Expected first argument to be of type boolean, string, number or null, but found array<string, 2> instead

Thanks for your time reading into this and your efforts you put into this are valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit a similar snag last year. Think I have a solution for you! You need to switch the ordering of the the `["get"]` argument and `["literal"]` arguments I believe. This snippet should work for you.

```js
map.setFilter("AW", [
  "any",
  ["in", ["get", "Business_Unit"], ["literal", ["Corporate", "Industrial"]]
]);
```

Here is a code sandbox link with a working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/mapbox-filters-example-hhtg5

Hope this helps! I have been writing a series of guides for Mapbox that you might be interested in too. Here are some links:

- [The Mapbox Developer's Handbook](https://gumroad.com/l/mapbox-handbook)
- [A Complete Guide to Sources and Layers in React and Mapbox GL JS](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/a-complete-guide-to-sources-and-layers-in-react-and-mapbox-gl-js)

Comment: Hey @tylerben, nice work there. I wanted to know if this handbook covers/teaches building expressions the easier way, because going through the mapbox docs is really painful.

Comment: @Gaurav Tiwari this is something that I am hoping to cover in the handbook with some concrete examples. I agree, the Mapbox docs are unfortunately really really painful when it comes to expressions. I am still in the process of developing the handbook so would love to hear what other things would be useful for you! Feel free to message me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/_btyler_) with any ideas!